# Scrapy xpath giving all matching elements

Tags: scrapy

I have one HTML file from which i want to extract anchor href values under specific DIV.
HTML file looks like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test page Vikrant </title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="mainContainer">
                <a href="https://india.net" class="logoShape">India</a>
                    <nav id="vik1">
                    <a href="https://aarushmay.com" class="closemobilemenu">home</a>
            <ul class="mainNav">
                    <li class="hide-submenu">
                        <a class="comingsoon1" href="https://aarushmay.com/fashion">Fashion </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
                <a href="https://maharashtra.net" class="logoShape">Maharashtra</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

The spider code is as below

```
import os
import scrapy
from scrapy import Selector
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "test"
  localfile_folder="localfiles"
  def start_requests(self):
    testFile = f'{self.localfile_folder}/t1.html'
    absoluteFileName = os.path.abspath(testFile)
    yield scrapy.Request(url=f'file:.///{absoluteFileName}', callback=self.parse)
  def parse(self, response):
    hrefElements = response.xpath('//nav[@id="vik1"]').xpath('//a/@href').getall()
    self.log(f'total records = {len(hrefElements)}')
```

The output i am getting is 4 anchor element. whereas i am expecting it to be 2. So i used "Selector" and stored the Div element in that and then try to extract the values of anchor elements. It worked fine.

```
    import os
import scrapy
from scrapy import Selector
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "test"
  localfile_folder="localfiles"
  def start_requests(self):
    testFile = f'{self.localfile_folder}/t1.html'
    absoluteFileName = os.path.abspath(testFile)
    yield scrapy.Request(url=f'file:.///{absoluteFileName}', callback=self.parse)
  def parse(self, response):
    listingDataSel = response.xpath('//nav[@id="vik1"]')
    exactElement = Selector(text=listingDataSel.get())
    hrefElements = exactElement.xpath('//a/@href').getall()
    self.log(f'total records = {len(hrefElements)}')
```

My question is why do i need to use intermediate Selector variable to store the extracted Div element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you did:

```
exactElement = Selector(text=listingDataSel.get())
```

you are creating a Selector which include just what you extracted in `listingDataSel.get()` but as follow:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <nav id="vik1">                    
      <a href="https://aarushmay.com" class="closemobilemenu">home
      </a>            
      <ul class="mainNav">                    
        <li class="hide-submenu">                        
          <a class="comingsoon1" href="https://aarushmay.com/fashion">Fashion 
          </a>                
        </li>            
      </ul>        
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you use the `text` parameter you created a new HTML doc, that's why you obtain just two anchor elements. You can check some examples at this [link](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#regular-expressions).

In your first code, you obtained 4 anchor elements because you are working with the original document. You can try this too:

```
response.xpath('//div/nav[@id="vik1"]//a/@href').extract()
```

and you can obtain the same result.

Comment: With this statement `response.xpath('//div/nav[@id="vik1"]//a/@href').extract()` you can extract the two anchor elements.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the way to extract 2 anchor elements. This is shorter way than extracting selector and then applying xpath.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [CSS Selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors) to extract the elements.

- They are faster than XPath.
- They are much easier to learn and implement.
- Code looks much cleaner too.

```
response.css('nav[id = "vik1"] a::attr(href)').getall()
```

This will give you the `href` values you are looking for.

Also, as per W3C standards, CSS selectors do not support selecting text nodes or attribute values. Here are some [Extensions to CSS Selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#extensions-to-css-selectors) that scrapy selectors provide which can be quite useful.

- to select text nodes, use `::text`
- [to select attribute values](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#selecting-element-attributes), use `::attr(name)` where `name` is the name of the attribute that you want the value of.

Answer (score 0):

did you try already to target the class div name?, For example, to get the text from the anchor elements in your HTML code is as follows.

```
response.xpath('//div[@class = "mainContainer"]/a/text()').extract()
```

From there, you just target the Href and u got them.

Check the documentation [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)